Outlook add-in event remove recurrence will not trigger the handler 'RecurrenceChanged'?
i add the handler 'RecurrenceChanged', and when i change the recurrence will trigger correctly. But when i click the remove btn, it will print nothing.
Here is the code.
Office.onReady(() => {
  isOfficeInitialized = true;
  render(App);
}).then(() => {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(
    Office.EventType.RecurrenceChanged,
    (eventArgs) => {
      console.log('eventArgs', eventArgs);
    },
    (result) => {
      console.log('result', result);
    }
  );
});

i read a lot doc and still don't know how to resolve it.
The ideal result:
When i click the remove btn, i can know it and do something callback  after it.
